# Reconnect if the link is stale

Tags: freebsd, ppp

I run FreeBsd box with pppd over Ethernet. Everything works just fine with only one exception. Sometimes, not too often, the connection becomes stale. Everything looks like if it is ok: ifconfig shows it is up, ppp says that the link is ok, but traffic does not come through. What I do is run `killall pppd` and then restart ppp manually. It reconnects and things are great again.

My question is: is there a setting in pppd (or mpd5, or anywhere else) that if set, makes ppp detect that the link is stale and reconnect automatically?

If there isn't such a setting, maybe there is another solution?

Comment: Did you set `ondemand` in your ppd config ?

Comment: No. I thought it serves different purpose. The thing is that connection is already established.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I came up with this solution.

```
enable lqr
set lqrperiod 5
```

Comment: Where are these set?

Answer (score 2):

Have you configured the following pppd [Link Control Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_Control_Protocol) options?  They control whether and how often pppd sends out LCP echoes to check whether the link is still alive or not, and how it responds if it isn't.

```
lcp-echo-failure n
lcp-echo-interval n
lcp-echo-adaptive
```

They combine well with the following options, which control whether pppd will try to restart a connection after termination, how long to delay before re-connecting, and how many times it will restart after failures:

```
persist
holdoff n
maxfail n
```

If maxfail is non-zero, you may also want a wrapper script or cron-job to restart pppd if it has exited completely (i.e. failures > maxfail setting).  A common reason for having maxfail > 0 is that a wrapper script can be written to have more intelligent responses (than just retry over and over again) to, e.g, a prolonged outage.

See the pppd man page for more details on these and other config options.

Comment: It sounds as a viable solution, but FreeBsd's pppd does not have these options. They are available on Linux only. But now that I know about LCP my chances to get it working are growing.

Comment: sorry, i thought freebsd used the same pppd as linux, based on a (faulty) vague recollection from years ago when i last used freebsd.  wrong.  maybe the `set redial` and `set reconnect` options would help.  `lqr` and `echo` also look relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a simple shell script to the crontab, that would periodically ping a known host, and restart service if the host cannot be reach.

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
ping -q -c3 google.com &> /dev/null
if [[ $? != "0" ]]
  then
    ppp_restart_command
fi
```

Name it for example `conn_check.sh`, add it to crontab and let it run every 60 sec.